# Inline Editor error in DialogFlow "Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined"

Tags: dialogflow-es

When I do the test on the DialogFlow or Slack itself it appears this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined
> at Message (/srv/index.js:32:30)

Clearly showing that the error is in `console.log (context.parameters.name);` he for some reason is not recognizing parameters

My code at DialogfLow:

index.js:

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const { Card, Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
        databaseURL: 'https://testechatbot-2020.firebaseio.com/'
    });
    process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';
    
    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
        console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
        console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
    
        function Nome(agent) {
            var banco = admin.database().ref('Dados/').push({
                Nome: agent.parameters['nome']
            });
            chave = banco.key;
        }
    
        function Valor(agent) {
            var banco = admin.database().ref('Dados/' + chave).update({
                Valor: agent.parameters['valor']
            });
        }
    
        function Mensagem(agent) {
            var name;
            var context = agent.context.get('awainting_nome');
            console.log (context.parameters.name);
      }
    
        let intentMap = new Map();
        intentMap.set('EntradaNome', Nome);
        intentMap.set('EntradaValores', Valor);
        intentMap.set('EntradaMensagem', Mensagem);
        agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
      "description": "Fluxo com envio de parametros para o Firebase",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "private": true,
      "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
      "author": "Google Inc.",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=10.0.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "firebase serve",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.16.1",
        "firebase-admin": "^8.13.0",
        "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.7.0",
        "dialogflow": "^1.2.0",
        "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.0",
        "@google-cloud/dialogflow": "^3.0.0"
      }
    }
```

Image links:

[EntradaNome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC5Vn.png)

[EntradaValores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjWsC.png)

[EntradaMensagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBMF5.png)

I made a few changes in index.js because I realized that in the "EntradaNome" intent the parameter name was "nome" and not "name" but I still kept the same error message

```
  function Mensagem(agent) {
       var context = agent.context.get('awainting_nome');
       let nome = context.parameters.nome;  
       console.log(nome);
  }
```

Comment: This is likely caused by the fact that ```awainting_nome``` is undefined. Could you add a screenshot of your intent setup which shows us how you are setting the awainting_nome context? A screenshot of the active contexts in the Dialogflow test window would also be helpful.

Comment: I added the images to her links

Comment: I'm seeing 3 of the same images, is that correct?

Comment: Tidying up I ended up saving everything in one image

Comment: Image links:

[EntradaNome][1]

[EntradaValores][2]

[EntradaMensagem][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC5Vn.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjWsC.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBMF5.png

Comment: the links are now right

Comment: Where are you setting the ```awainting_nome``` context? I don't see an output context in your intents or any code calls like ```agent.contexts.set("awainting_nome",5)```. Are you sure that you are setting it? If it isn't set, it explains why you are getting the error since the context is never there.

Comment: I managed to get him to receive it and removed the error because in my EntryMessage intent he reset the previous contexts so he didn't call

Comment: Now I don’t know how I go about sorting this problem out